# Number validate regex

Tags: javascript, regex

From jquery.validate.js, this regex is used to validate a number.  The problem is that it fails on .33 and passes on 0.33.  I need to make it pass with, or without, the leading 0.

```
^-?(?:\d+|\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})+)(?:\.\d+)?$
```

Comment: What are your criteria for a "valid" number? The above returns false for numbers like *2.3e3*, *1/3*, *+3*, and *2,35*, which are all considered valid by some.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A positive lookahead such as `(?=[.])` can be used to ensure that the strings either starts with a dot (`.`) or follow the previously defined pattern.

```
^-?(?:(?=[.])|\d+|\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})+)(?:\.\d+)?$
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
^-?(?:\d+|\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})+)?(?:\.\d+)?$
```

The extra question mark (spot it!) will make all the part before the decimal point optional.

Comment: The above regexp will flag an empty string `""` as a valid number, which is far from correct. Check out my post to see a proper way of altering the given regular expression to get the desired effect.

Answer (score 1):

There are simpler ways to tell if a string refers to a number-

```
function isNumber(str){
    return parseFloat(str)=== Number(str);
}
```

Comment: though `parseFloat` and `Number` cannot handle numbers written as `100,000,000.42`.

Answer (score 0):

This may be late but I have a better answer. Try this:

```
^-?((\d+)|([1-9]\d{0,2}(,\d{3})+)|(?=\.))(\.\d+)?$
```

Both the solutions by *refp* and *solendil* above will accept a number like **0,123,456** or **000,123** as valid. These are obviously not valid numbers.

This solution makes sure that **the part before the first comma starts with a non-zero digit**. It also takes care of the empty string issue that *refp* pointed out.